# I would like to check if the file name inserted by the user match the name of a the file in the directory

Tags: java

I would like to know how to check if a file exists in the directory or if the name of the file typed in by the  user matches what is in the directory and if it dont i out put a certain msg.. I  am using FileDialog. That is if the user types in the name of a file it loops through the directory
for a file with that name. If no match is found then a message should be printed.

```
    FileDialog fileWindow = 
       new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Tash & David's File Founder System");
    fileWindow.setVisible(true);

    if (fileWindow.getFile() != null) {         
        File fileDirectory = new File(fileWindow.getDirectory());           
        String[] Directory = fileDirectory.list();          
        for (; i < Directory.length; i++) {                         
            if(Directory[i].startsWith(fileWindow.getFile())){              
                System.out.print("yes");                                    
            }                            
        }                       
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you Sure");
    }
```

Comment: @Tudor I would like to check if the name of the file without its extension typed in the Filedialog box exists...if it does not exist then a message is displayed

Answer (score 1):

use `exist()` method. Read [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html)

Comment: yeah but that does not work the way i wrote teh code..can u help me

Comment: What you are trying to achieve by your code if you want to check the file that gets selected from `FileChooser` then why don't you just check [`fileChooser.getSelectedFile().exist()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile())

Comment: I am using filedialog...it does does use getSelectedFile();

Comment: then you can do new `File(fileDialog.getDirectory()+File.saperator+fileDialog.getFile()).exist()`

Comment: that line of code does not work...cud u place it in my code so i can see where it should go

Comment: Can you tell me  what is builds as String ? by `fileDialog.getDirectory()+File.saperator+fileDialog.getFile()`

Comment: fileDirectory gets the directory of the file. The String array Directory story all the files in the directory named fileDirectory. I created afor loop to loop through the string array Directory. In the loop it checks if the filename inserted by the user in fileWindow.getFile() matches the name of a file in the string array Directory. If a match is found it should say a match is found otherwise no match was found.

Comment: what is the final string looks like if you print `fileDialog.getDirectory()+File.saperator+fileDialog.getFile()` ??

Comment: but i have to loop through the directory...and its not working. Say for eg I am in the directory named C:\Users\BROWN\Pictures and i want to find an image name flow without its extension which is a jpeg. I would need to loop the directory to c if i find a file name flow. if the file is found i do something if it is not found i do something else

Comment: but why do you iterate a loop you can do it in a single line code as I mentioned earlier use `new File(fileDialog.getDirectory()+File.saperator+fileDialog.getFile()).exist()`

Comment: so you are say that i should replace the for loop with this: new File(fileDialog.getDirectory()+File.saperator+fileDialog.getFile()).exist()

Comment: Yes <!------------------------------->

Comment: That works in a way but i have to put in the file extension too in the search bar which shouldnt be so. I should b able to put in jus the name of the fiel and it finds it

Comment: well extension is a part of file name

Answer (score 0):

Use an `.exists()` method.

One method: `java.io.File.exists()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29

Another method: `java.nio.file.Path.exists()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29

A simple Google search normally turns up results for easy questions such as this :)

***Edit***:
For simplicity (added all the code to check a file exists in the `if()`):

```
FileDialog fileWindow = 
   new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Tash & David's File Founder System");
fileWindow.setVisible(true);

if (fileWindow.getFile() != null && new File(fileWindow.getDirectory()+File.separator+fileWindow.getFile()).exists()) {
    File fileDirectory = new File(fileWindow.getDirectory());           
    String[] Directory = fileDirectory.list();          
    for (; i < Directory.length; i++) {                         
        if(Directory[i].startsWith(fileWindow.getFile())){              
            System.out.print("yes");                                    
        }                            
    }                       
}
else
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you Sure");
}
```

You can optimise it, but you can see what needs to be done to check the existence of a file. Let me know if it works, and select this as a suitable answer :)

Comment: I am not finding finding the answer though. could u help me?

Comment: Updated my answer with your original block of code + the statement to check the file exists.

Comment: It is not quite right. I am suppose to type in the name of teh file without its extension and search for that file in the directory and if the file is not found it outputs an error